# Problem with Validate Anti Forgery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-2, antiforgerytoken

I have a problem regarding MVC Anti forgery token.
When I do my authentication I have pseudo code like this:

```
var user = userRepository.GetByEmail(email);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = user;
```

by doing so I'm able to get the current user in my code like this:

```
var user = HttpContext.Current.User as EntityUser;
```

This works fine until I add the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute to an action.
When I add the attribute I get

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

If I comment out this line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = user;
```

The antiforgery validation works fine, but the I don't have my convenient way of getting my "EntityUser" from the HttpContext.
Any ideas of how to work around this?
Best regards
Mikael

Comment: I don't think these are related, which makes your observations seem odd.  I'm using a custom Principal and the AFT in an app and it works fine.

Comment: But if I comment out the row where I set CurrentPrincipal and Current.user the Antiforgery validation works.
Are you using MVC2? (Iforgot to mention I'm using MVC2). As I understood it MS have changed the implementation of AntiForgeryToken.
See here for a SO question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697772/mvc-2-antiforgerytoken-why-symmetric-encryption-iprinciple

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that those are related. When you add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to your controller action you also need to add the hidden field inside your form:

```
<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
```

If you are submitting it through AJAX you always need to send this token along the request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually AntiForgeryToken uses HttpContextBase.User in validation. See AntiForgeryWorker.Validate