# Why does ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute allow anonymous tokens?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, csrf

In ASP.NET MVC, the validation logic called by ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute allows anonymous anti-forgery tokens, i.e. tokens without any user-specific information such as IIdentity.Name or ClaimUid.

So, if claims are not used and HttpContext.User is not set after login (not uncommon), a malicious user of the system can stage a CSRF-attack against any other user, using the malicious user's own legitimately acquired anti-forgery tokens.

This doesn't seem desirable. Why are anonymous tokens allowed?

Comment: I have answered your question except for one part - what do you mean HttpContext.User is not set after login?  The only way that happens is if login fails or you do not do a Redirect after processing the POSTed login form.

Comment: @Tommy If you don't explicitly set HttpContext.User (like FormsAuthentication does by reading the cookie set at log-in), HttpContext.User will be equal for all logged in users, and therefore "anonymous".

Comment: I have never seen that behavior in any application that we have made in MVC.  Once we have set the Auth Cookie (in Identity or FormsAuthentication) - we never have to "manually" set the cookie or HttpContext.User.  I would be curious as to how your authentication is setup.  Either way, to address your question, the AntiForgery token is not used to authorize resources, only to validate the request and user response originated from your server

Comment: If you don't use FormsAuthentication or some other Identity provider, you have to set HttpContext.User yourself - otherwise it will be equal for all logged in users. But it is easy to forget this if you have no use for HttpContext.User.

Comment: Gotcha - I thought you were using one of those and were still manually having to control that.  My misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anti-CSRF system in MVC allows anonymous users because **it needs to protect the login page**, and by definition you're anonymous before you've logged in.  In particular, the attack it's trying to defend against is [Login CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Forging_login_requests).

Since the anti-CSRF token is split across both an HTTP cookie and a hidden <input> element, whether an attacker will be able to pull off login CSRF depends on where he's sitting.  Sure - you might be able to convince my browser to submit a <form> containing *your* token, but my browser will submit *my* cookie to the server along with the request.  The cookie and form token encode more than just the string "anonymous": they also contain a random identifier that links the two together.  In this scenario, you still wouldn't be able to pull off a login CSRF attack against me since you don't know the random identifier contained within my cookie.

If the attacker shares a domain with the target web site (e.g., attacker.shareddomain.com and bank.shareddomain.com), then the attacker can set a cookie for *.shareddomain.com and overwrite the victim's cookie with one of his own choosing.  This would allow a CSRF attack to take place.  You'd need another mechanism (like 2FA or HTML5 local storage) to prevent CSRF attacks in a shared subdomain scenario.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of Login CSRF. Thanks! Apart from the subdomain-attack you describe, there's also the Ajax case which needs a cookie-less solution. For example as described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't allow anonymous tokens!

For some reasons (Which I don't know myself!) the token is written in both HTTP Header and the cookie. However, only that token written in COOKIE will be checked. In other words:

1) if you prevent cookies from being sent and your ActionMethod has the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]` attribute, you'll get the following exception:

`The required anti-forgery form field __requestverificationtoken is not present`.

2) You can change the token written in the Http Header...! - Nothing wrong will happen...!

**The main purpose of the *AntiForgeryToken*:**

It's a solution for ensuring that the form data received to the server, is submitted through the form which is created and sent to the client by the server(Not from a forged form!).

So, If two legal users change their cookies and submit the form, the server will **ACCEPT** both of them! Because the server created and sent both of that forms!(And indeed, both of tokens...!)

Read more about `AntiForgeryToken` [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/what-is-antiforgerytoken-and-why-do-i.html)

Comment: Yes, anonymous tokens, i.e. tokens without user- or claims information, are allowed. My question is not on the use of tokens.

Comment: @AndreasHallberg - But your answer is hidden in the use of tokens: `It's a solution for ensuring that the form data received to the server, is submitted through the form which is created and sent to the client by the server(Not from a forged form!)` That's why it behave like what you say...

Answer (score 2):

`AntiForgery` tokens are used to prevent CSRF (cross-site requests), they are not used to ensure that the data coming back is from an authorized user, that is what the `Identity` and  `FormsAuthentication` libraries are for (authentication and authorization).

The `AntiForgery` token uses some known pieces of information to generate a random string of text that is included with the POST response.  One piece of this information is the user name. It is possible to have a POSTed form without needing to require authentication (anonymous site searching, anonymous survey, etc).  This is why the `AntiForgery` token has to be allowed to be used with the username *anonymous*.

Given that the role of the `AntiForgery` token is to only prevent CSRF attacks (POSTing to your server from a completely different website), then the use of anonymous usernames in the `AntiForgery` token should not be a concern.  When someone posts back to your server and they have to be logged in to perform that action, you should be catching that with the `[Authorize]` attribute.  That attribute, along with the AntiForgery token will ensure that a) an authorized user has made this request and b) they did so from your website and not from outside of your website.

Comment: My point is that anonymous AntiForgery tokens do NOT prevent CSRF since if the attacker have access to the same web application as the victim, he can use his tokens in the forged request. The web application can not distinguish the attacker's token from the victim's.

Comment: @AndreasHallberg - that is not a CSRF.  CSRF is if someone can post to your website at `www.myurl.com` from `www.badurl.com`.  Again, these are *NOT* used for authenticating or authorizing a request.  You are describing something more along the lines of Session hijacking with your concerns, which is why, if you need to associate a request with a specific user, you should be using a FormsAuthentication cookie/token and not the AntiForgery by itself.

Comment: Yes, it is CSRF. I my question I describe a regular CSRF-attack that has the (attacker's) anonymous anti-forgery tokens embedded in the forged request. The application can not distinguish the attacker's tokens from the ones the user would supply in a genuine request.

Answer (score 1):

`AntiForgery` token contains the `username` and for `anonymous` user `username` will be empty. after user logon and next use of generated token, token validation will be failed because the empty username contained in the initial token is different than the currently authenticated username. for more info [read this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1560362.aspx?A%20required%20anti%20forgery%20token%20was%20not%20supplied%20or%20was%20invalid).