# Do ASP.NET MVC CSRF Anti-Forgery Tokens expire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, csrf

I am implementing CSRF Anti-Forgery protection in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application. In particular, I am referencing the approach described by Mike Wasson on the [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks) to protect controller methods that respond to AJAX requests, such as in WebAPI controllers. This approach makes use of the [AntiForgery.GetTokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery.gettokens(v=vs.111).aspx) method to generate user-based cryptographic anti-forgery tokens, and then [AntiForgery.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158363(v=vs.111).aspx) to verify that the submitted tokens belong to the current user.

My question is this: is there a time-to-live for these tokens? Do they expire, and if so, how long are they good for? The documentation is mute on the subject.

I do not want to permit non-expiring tokens in my system. Additionally, I want to communicate to the client how much time they have before requesting a new token is necessary. I can implement expiring tokens, if necessary, using [FormsAuthentication.Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); however, if expiration is already built into the `AntiForgery` class' methods, then I'd like to spare myself the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I would like to know this too. Try looking at the source code: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgery.cs

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that two tokens are generated by every vulnerable HTTP POST and sent directly to the server. Therefore, if you click the "Submit" button on a form, two tokens are generated: a cookie and a form value, both based on the user credentials, as to be read here (nice written article): http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

The cookie token, that actually can expire is redundant and not necessary for the system except for the case where an anonymous authentication is tried. E.g. see here (first answer):
[MVC 2 AntiForgeryToken - Why symmetric encryption + IPrinciple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697772/mvc-2-antiforgerytoken-why-symmetric-encryption-iprinciple)

Still, your other token is not-readable for attackers and these tokens are generated with each new request. Therefore, no need to worry about the expiration date.

**Edit**: Actually, this all can also be read in the comment section of the article you are referring to (Mike Wasson) ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the concepts of how the two tokens work, and understand the subtle but different approaches for HTML forms vs. AJAX requests. My question, however, is specifically whether the tokens expire, which is not discussed in the documentation or in the comments of Mike Wasson's post. Cheers!

Comment: @kbrimington The [first article above](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages) in the IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider section towards the bottom of the page, seems to imply that it does not have an expiration.  It says you COULD implement additional checks and states "The validation routine could implement a timeout (by checking the current time against the time that was stored when the token was created), a nonce checking routine, or any other desired logic."  Did you ever get a definitive answer about token expiration?

Comment: @DavidYates, thanks for bringing this to my attention. At the time, I concluded they must not expire, and I built my own expiry logic. I do not recall this section being present in the article 2.5 years ago when I asked my question. It does appear to be the intent of `IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider` to permit easy customization of the token and its validation logic, including the ability to implement timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the cookies that are created through the browser.  They are session cookies without an expiration.  That means when you close the browser the cookies will be deleted.